# Problem on remainder theorem on polynomials

Tags: polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find a polynomial that leaves the remainder $15$ when divided by $x-3$ and $2x+1$ when divided by $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $2x^2-2x+3$?

Answer (score 0):

We seek a polynomial such that $p(3)=15$, $p(1)=3$, and $p'(1)=2$.

If we assume $p(x)=cx^2+bx+a$, that yields three equations; can you solve them for $c$, $b$, and $a$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn:  I see your point, but why did I get $2x^2-2x+3=2(x-1)^2+(2x+1)?$

Comment: I don't know what you did to get that

Comment: @DavidQuinn:  $2x^2-2x+3=2(x-1)^2+(2x+1)$ is correct, isn't it?

Comment: yes that's right so your example works!